# Tableview getItems.AddAll causes java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

Update:  The cause is tblTimeDataClock  is null.Any idea why?

I am getting a Tableview getItems.AddAll causes java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException when calling the getItems().AddAll() method. I have tried following the various examples on the internet but nothing seems so work.  The exception occurs at the tblTimeDataClock.getItems().addAll(data) call.

I do see a warning on the new PropertyValue call saying Redundant Type arguments in new expression.  Not sure if that has anything to do with it,

What am I doing wrong?

I put together this abbreviated example.

```
@FXML
private TableView<Test> tblTimeDataClock;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Test, String> colTimeSeconds;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Test, String> colDataVolts;

@FXML
private TableColumn<Test, String> colClockVolts;   


@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    listTimeDataClockMeasurement = new <Test>ArrayList();

    colTimeSeconds.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Test, String>("n1"));
    colDataVolts.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Test, String>("n2"));
    colDataVolts.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Test, String>("n3"));

    ObservableList<Test> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();      

    tblTimeDataClock.getItems().addAll(data);


}
```

The Test class

```
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

  public class Test {

private final SimpleStringProperty n1;
private final SimpleStringProperty n2;
private final SimpleStringProperty n3;

public String getN1() {
    return n1.get();
}

public String getN2() {
    return n2.get();
}


public String getN3() {
    return n3.get();
}

public Test(String n1, String n2, String n3) {
    this.n1 = new SimpleStringProperty(n1);
    this.n2 = new SimpleStringProperty(n2);
    this.n3 = new SimpleStringProperty(n3);
}
```

}

FXML added per request

```
                   <content>
                        <TableView fx:id="tblDataClock" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                          <columns>
                            <TableColumn fx:id="colTimeSeconds" prefWidth="116.0" text="Time" />
                            <TableColumn id="colData" fx:id="colDataVolts" prefWidth="127.0" text="Data" />
                              <TableColumn id="colClock" fx:id="colClockVolts" prefWidth="137.0" text="Clock" />
                          </columns>
                        </TableView>
                     </content>
```

Looks like the cause might be java.lang.NullPointerException
    at serialdecoder.SerialDecoderController.initialize(SerialDecoderController.java:60)

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
file:/E:/Data/Java/SerialDecoder/dist/run67790734/SerialDecoder.jar!/serialdecoder/SerialDecoder.fxml

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2579)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at serialdecoder.SerialDecoder.start(SerialDecoder.java:22)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at serialdecoder.SerialDecoderController.initialize(SerialDecoderController.java:60)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
    ... 17 more
Exception running application serialdecoder.SerialDecoder
```

Comment: What's the exception's cause's message & stack trace?

Comment: You should probably post the FXML as well as the complete stack trace.

Comment: are you sure that the object on which you're calling `addAll()` supports the operation? That method is one of these blankety-blank "optional" ones in the Collection package.

Comment: @arcy The default backing list for a table view is modifiable, if that is what you're asking. I have no idea what you mean by a 'blankety-blank "optional"' method.

Comment: Sorry -- I was disappointed that the method was made optional in the Collections definitions, and that phrase substituted for a mild curse.  The fact that the table view is modifiable is not enough; as I understand it, a collection type may choose to implement that method or not, it is not required to satisfy the requirements of the interface. It is allowed to throw an "UnsupportedException", though if you're invoking it through reflection, then "InvocationTargetException" is what I would expect.

Comment: We can go at this from another direction -- what makes you think `addAll()` is a method on the return from `getItems()`?

Comment: @arcy Classes that implement interfaces in the collections API can choose to be unmodifiable. They do this by throwing `UnsupportedOperationException`s if a method that would modify the list is invoked. Consequently, methods that modify a collection (of which `addAll()` is certainly one) are called "optional".

Comment: @arcy I don't understand your last comment.

Comment: And line 60 is `tblTimeDataClock.getItems().addAll(data);` ?

Answer (score 0):

Found it!  My TableView id was incorrect in my FXML file. :(